# scipy.optimize.minimize constraints problem

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I have a minimize task:
That function work fine:

```
def list_year_payments(clear_payments, number_periods):
    payments = clear_payments[:number_periods+1]
    eq_const = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x:   np.sum(x*discoun_coeff(number_periods,d_r))-future_value_of_aim}
    eq_const_1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[0]/x[0] - payments[1]/x[1])}
    eq_const_2 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[1]/x[1] - payments[2]/x[2])}
    eq_const_3 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[2]/x[2] - payments[3]/x[3])}
    eq_const_4 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[3]/x[3] - payments[4]/x[4])}
    eq_const_5 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[4]/x[4] - payments[5]/x[5])}
    eq_const_6 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[5]/x[5] - payments[6]/x[6])}
    bounds = ((0,70),)*(number_periods+1)
    res = minimize(aim, X, method='SLSQP', constraints=[eq_const,eq_const_1, eq_const_2,eq_const_3,eq_const_4,eq_const_5, eq_const_6] , bounds=bounds)
    return res.x
```

But in real all constraints depend on '''number_periods''': so I need one instruction for all constraints for to six.

```
def minimizze(clear_payments, number_periods):
    payments = clear_payments[:number_periods+1]
    eq_const = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x*discoun_coeff(number_periods,d_r))-future_value_of_aim}
    eq_const_1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x : np.sum([payments[i]/x[i] ==    payments[i+1]/x[i+1] for i in range(number_periods)])-number_periods}

    bounds = ((1,70),)*(number_periods+1)
    res = minimize(aim, X, method='SLSQP', constraints=[eq_const,eq_const_1] , bounds=bounds)
    return res.x
```

but this didn't work return array of start x iterations(like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]), looks like eq_const about sum that should be 470 didn't work.

all code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

clear_payments = np.array([90,100,110,120,130,120,110,100,90])
future_value_of_aim = 470
number_periods = 6
d_r = 0.12


def discoun_coeff(per,d_r):
    x = np.ones(per+1)
    k = np.empty(per+1)
    for i in range(per+1):
        k[i]=x[i]*(1+d_r)**i

    return k[::-1]


def aim(X):
    return np.sum(X)

X = np.ones(number_periods+1)
x = np.linspace(0,70,7000)
def paymets_year(clear_payments, number_periods):
    payments = clear_payments[:number_periods+1]

    eq_const = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x*discoun_coeff(number_periods,d_r))-future_value_of_aim}

    eq_const_1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[0]/x[0] - payments[1]/x[1])}
    eq_const_2 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[1]/x[1] - payments[2]/x[2])}
    eq_const_3 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[2]/x[2] - payments[3]/x[3])}
    eq_const_4 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[3]/x[3] - payments[4]/x[4])}
    eq_const_5 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[4]/x[4] - payments[5]/x[5])}
    eq_const_6 = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[5]/x[5] - payments[6]/x[6])}
    bounds = ((0,70),)*(number_periods+1)
    res = minimize(aim, X, method='SLSQP', constraints=[eq_const,eq_const_1,       eq_const_2,eq_const_3,eq_const_4,eq_const_5, eq_const_6] , bounds=bounds)
    return res.x

p=paymets_year(clear_payments, number_periods)
p
array([38.34895684, 42.60995205, 46.87094726, 51.13194246, 55.39293767,
   51.13194246, 46.87094726])
```

Comment: Can you please post the res.message and res.success?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to generalize

```
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[0]/x[0] - payments[1]/x[1])}
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[1]/x[1] - payments[2]/x[2])}
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[2]/x[2] - payments[3]/x[3])}
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[3]/x[3] - payments[4]/x[4])}
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[4]/x[4] - payments[5]/x[5])}
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (payments[5]/x[5] - payments[6]/x[6])}
```

for other values than `number_periods = 6`, and you tried to do this with

```
 {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x : np.sum([payments[i]/x[i] ==    payments[i+1]/x[i+1] for i in range(number_periods)])-number_periods}
```

but failed, despite ideationally the computations are equivalent. In reality though, the optimization likely fails due to the discontinuity of the `==` relation together with the imprecision of floating-point arithmetic.
A better approach would be more similar to the original:

```
 {'type': 'eq',
  'fun': lambda x: np.sum([(payments[i]/x[i]-payments[i+1]/x[i+1])**2 for i in range(number_periods)])
 }
```

Here subtraction is used as before, and to let the overall sum for equal quotients approximate zero the individual differences are squared.
But beware: With this single constraint summarizing the original constraints, the optimization converges rather poorly. Better keep using individual constraints; you can generate them for any `number_periods`:

```
    constr = [eq_const]
    for i in range(number_periods):
        constr.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, i=i: payments[i]/x[i]-payments[i+1]/x[i+1]})
    res = minimize(aim, X, method='SLSQP', constraints=constr, bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question why you initialized $i=i$ in lambda function?

Comment: If I don't use `i=i`, the lambda functions don't "remember" the value of `i` at the time of their definition in the loop, but rather use whatever value `i` has at the time of their invocation, and so wouldn't work right.